# What is the recommended way of registering ContainerRequestFilter in Dropwizard 2.x?

Tags: dropwizard

I am using dropwizard 1.3.9 and working on moving to the latest dropwizard 2.x.

Right now I have a `ContainerRequestFilter` like below

```
@Authenticate
public class BasicAuthenticator implements ContainerRequestFilter {
      @Context
      private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;
      private final CollectorChannel collectorChannel ;
      private final ConfigStore configStore;

      public BasicAuthenticator(final CollectorChannel collectorChannel, final ConfigStore configStore)


      @Override
      public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

            String requestIpAddress = servletRequest.getRemoteAddr();
            String requestHost = servletRequest.getRemoteHost();
            logger.info("Request originates from IP {} Host {}", requestIpAddress, requestHost);

            String authHeader = requestContext.getHeaderString("Authorization");

            Optional<User> user = AuthUtils.getUserBasicAuth(authHeader);
            if (!user.isPresent()) {
                requestContext.abortWith(responseUnAuthenticated());
                return;
            }

            if (!isAuthentic(user.get())) {
                requestContext.abortWith(responseUnAuthenticated());
            }


            if (!isValidLiSource(requestIpAddress) && !isValidLiSource(requestHost)) {
                requestContext.abortWith(responseUnauthorized());
                return;
            }
        }
}
```

I register it like below

```
final BasicAuthenticator basicAuthenticator = new BasicAuthenticator(collectorChannel, configStore);
environment.jersey().register(basicAuthenticator);
```

In [migration doc](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fdropwizard%2Fdropwizard%2Fwiki%2FUpgrade-guide-1.3.x-to-2.0.x%23context-injection-on-fields-in-resource-instances&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNEPat4zG5QLh34x6oFEls70IdwA9Q) it is mentioned that

> Migrating resource instances with field context injections to
>   Dropwizard 2.0 involves pushing the field into a parameter in the
>   desired endpoint

But `filter()` method does not get the context as argument. Can someone let me know what is the recommended way to register a `ContainerRequestFilter` like above in 2.x ?

Comment: _"But filter() method does not get the context as argument"_ - Can you elaborate on this? What errors are you getting?

Comment: How can I get the `HttpServletRequest` in the `filter()` method if I remove the `servletRequest` as instance variable from `BasicAuthenticator` as per the [migration guide](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fdropwizard%2Fdropwizard%2Fwiki%2FUpgrade-guide-1.3.x-to-2.0.x%23context-injection-on-fields-in-resource-instances&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNEPat4zG5QLh34x6oFEls70IdwA9Q). `ContainerRequestFilter` does not have any `filter(ContainerRequestContext, HttpServletRequest)` method.

Comment: They are talking about resource classes. What you have is a filter. Have you tried it to see if it still works?

Comment: Thanks. It is not throwing any error but that part in the migration guide I had confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Paul Samostha above and also answered in the [forum](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/dropwizard-user/uW1aeIO9nLg/utYydzgYAQAJ) like below

> Hm, the migration guide talks about resource instances but not
>   ContainerRequestFilters. For what it's worth I tried this out in 2.0.8
>   with a field-injected context and instance registration like you have
>   written above and it seems to work for me. HttpServletRequest is
>   injected and available when the filter is executed.